# Actions click script - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, junit

The code below is a selenium script I created with the Selenium IDE, I'm trying to get it to click 250 pixels from the technology button which should click the 'education' tab. You can see by running the script that the 'education' tab is highlighted as if its moused over but the console gives the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
>   point (753.5, 107.51666259765625). Other element would receive the
>   click

Using:

- FireFox 45.0.0.1
- Selenium Webdriver 2.53.1

```
    package MyPackage;

    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class BBC {
       private String baseUrl;
       private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
       private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    static ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    static FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("selenium");
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);

       @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

      @Test
       public void testBBCtest2() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=h4qDV93mBOjR8gfVi4qwDg&gws_rd=ssl");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("BBC news");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home - BBC News")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='site-container']/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/a/span")).click();
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='site-container']/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/a/span"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
    builder.moveToElement(link, 250, 0).click().build().perform();
     }

     @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
      String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
      if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
       }
     }

     private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
       try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
       } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
      }
     }

     private boolean isAlertPresent() {
      try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
       } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
       }
      } 

     private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
       try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
      } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
     }
     }
     }
```

Comment: What do you want actually?? where is `education` link in your page.YOur question is not clear..Please explain clearly...

Comment: The education button is to the right of the technology button, by 250 pixels, the website is a public website if you want to try this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
builder.moveToElement(link, 250, 0).click().build().perform();
```

Try :

```
builder.moveToElement(link, 250, 0);
builder.clickAndHold();
builder.release();
builder.build();
builder.perform();
```

Comment: No luck with this, Test is passing but its not attempting to click anything by the looks of it.