# Selenium Scrolling element, inside page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Good night friends !, I'm having a hard time getting all the elements inside an element of the page, what happens is the following:

I have a "div" element and inside it there are several messages literally a chat, which loads the information when its scroll is moved, only I researched several tutorials about scroll manipulation and I didn't find something that solves my problem, Can anyone give me a light? some article something i can read understand how to do that.

Basically it is "infinite" scroll with elements inside it that to view I need to climb this scroll and another solution I found is to make the page zoom out of it by the command of (Ctrl + -) or using the mouse scroll with the ctrl + scroll, but I must be doing something wrong I used this line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name ("html"). send_keys (Keys.CONTROL + "\ ue027")
```

Nothing happens.

I can't use the document.body.syle.zoom, because the elements don't load

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Initially,locate that element and then operate it,we can do that with Actions class

```
public class ElementLevelScrolling {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\batch250\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653910/actions-click-script-selenium");
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/following-sibling::pre[@class='lang-java s-code-block hljs']"));
//to view the operations clearly moving the element into visible area
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", ele);
Thread.sleep(3000);
Actions a=new Actions(driver);
a.sendKeys(ele,Keys.END).perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
a.sendKeys(ele,Keys.HOME).perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
a.sendKeys(ele,Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
a.sendKeys(ele,Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform();
    }

}
```